# Powershell-Command to download a file with admin rights

Tags: powershell, ssis, sql-server-agent

I try do download a file via a powershell command. The command I use is simple:

```
Start-BitsTransfer  -Source  'https://download.com/file.zip' -Destination 'E:\test\file.zip'
```

I can run the command in PS succesfully. But now I want to run it with elevated rights. [So I gooogled and found this solution](https://www.ryandrane.com/2015/06/run-script-or-command-as-admin-in-powershell/):

There it says the command should be:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb Runas -ArgumentList "-Command &amp; {get-process}"
```

So I tried adjusting it for my use case:

```
 Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb Runas -ArgumentList "-Command &amp; {Start-BitsTransfer  -Source  'https://download.com/file.zip' -Destination 'E:\test\file.zip'}"
```

But all is does is open a new PS-Window and closing it right after. Where is my mistake?

Comment: `&amp;` --> `&`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change to this

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb Runas -ArgumentList "& {Start-BitsTransfer  -Source  'https://download.com/file.zip' -Destination 'E:\test\file.zip'}"
```

Note the window will close after the execution completes. If you would like to see the output/errors (such as what would be shown in your non working example) just add another command to pause.

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb Runas -ArgumentList "& {Start-BitsTransfer  -Source  'https://download.com/file.zip' -Destination 'E:\test\file.zip';pause}"
```

`&` is used to invoke a command. It's useful for executing strings or scriptblocks. It runs in a child runspace.

```
& 'Get-Host'
& 'Write-Host' Hello -Fore Green
& {Write-Host Goodbye -Fore Cyan}
```

`;` is used to separate different commands on the same line.

```
& {$name = 'Doug';Write-Host Hello $name}
```

You can also use a period to invoke a scriptblock in the current runspace. In the previous command the $name variable would be empty in the callers scope where the following command would leave the variable defined.

```
& {$name = 'Doug';Write-Host Hello $name}
$name # empty as it all happens in the child scope
```

vs

```
. {$name = 'Doug';Write-Host Hello $name}
$name # populated because it's brought into the caller's scope
```